# Why does my Autofilter used to delete rows with zeros remove the headers after the fact?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm trying to delete rows in an expense report where the expense was 0, as that information is unimportant. I'm using an Autofilter to filter the rows with only zeros in the amount column, and deleting those rows. The problem is that when the code moves on to the next step after this task, it leaves my report document without the headers it previously had, and these headers are very important.

I have tried changing the range from "AB1:AB" to "AB2:AB" and that did nothing, and in the second, concatenated range value I have tried changing "AB" to "AB2", which returned an error stating that the "method 'range' of object '_global' failed."

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Range("AB1:AB" & Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(3)(1).Row).AutoFilter 1, 0#, xlAnd, 0
            Range("AB2:AB" & Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(3)(1).Row).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Just to check - are they zeros or blank?

Comment: @BigBen they are zeros, not blank. I have both 0# and 0 in the filter criteria because sometimes, the formatting of certain cells turn "0" into "0."

Comment: Before deleting rows, can you add a `Debug.Print Range("AB" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`? What is the result in the Immediate Window?

Comment: @BigBen I did, but the highlighted line is the one above the row deletion line, so the autofilter line. should I do the debug.print before that line and tell you what I get?

Comment: Do you still have `"AB2" & Rows.Count`? If so, change back to `"AB"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is because if there are no 0's in column AB, your existing code filters to only show the header row and is then deleting.  I have added some code to loop through Column AB and check to see if any 0's exist prior to actioning your existing code.

I am editing this answer, it no longer uses your AutoFilter methods.  The below code should do what you are trying to achieve and it gets away from the potential issues with deleting rows inside a loop as was highlighted in the comments.

I have edited again to correct the issue you described with the code delting values that included a 0 (ex. 10.05).

```
Sub Delete_Zero_Rows()

Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Set the first and last row to loop through
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    'Loops from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

        'Checks the values in column AB
        With .Cells(Lrow, "AB")

            If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                If .Value = "0" Then .EntireRow.Delete

            End If
        End With
      Next Lrow
    End With
End Sub
```

Remember to replace "Sheet1" in my code with whatever your worksheet is called.

This should fix your issue!

Comment: Hi, I have integrated your code into my own (the only changes I made were the sheet name and the name of the LastRow variable) and when I ran it, I made sure I had a row with a "0." in the document to test that the code did its job. The code however threw up an error, stating that it had not found any cells matching my criteria, and just stopped there. It's highly unusual for the reports that we run to have zeros, but sometimes they make their way in somehow. But if this code is going to cause errors every time there isn't a row with a zero in the amount column, that's bad, lol. Any advice?

Comment: Please see the edits I made to my answer / code above.  I moved away from the `Autofilter` you were using but this should do what you need without the error / it will handle 0s or no 0s without any issues.

Comment: Did that work for you?  If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it with the green check mark to select it as a qualified / effective answer.  Cheers!

Comment: It looks like it should work. The only problem I'm running into with it is that I keep getting "Runtime error 9 - subscript out of range" with the debug highlight applied to the line where you set sht1 to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("<insert sheetname here>"). I've copied and pasted the worksheet name into the parentheses, and it still keeps giving me errors. I even tried creating a veriable, sheetName, to stand in as a string to which I assigned the name of the worksheet. Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind, but you could do away with the `sht1` and simply use `worksheets("sheet1")` instead and that would work.  Ex. `With sht1.Range("AB:AB")` --> `With worksheets("sheet1").range("AB:AB")`   Just remember to change `sheet1` to whatever you worksheet is called.

Comment: Okay, that worked, however now the code is finding any row with a 0 anywhere in the AB column and deleting it, including AB cells in which there are 0s included in a larger number. For example, it deleted my test row with the 0 in it, but it also deleted one with 32.05 in it, and several tens of other similar rows. Is there a way to screen to check if any other characters besides a 0 are in the cells in question, and if there are, to skip the deletion?

Comment: Sheesh! Sorry about that - I updated the answer above with a new bit of code.  I tested it for both the issues you described with previous answers and this new answer fixes both.  I think we got it this time!

Comment: Alright, it's working perfectly! Thank you so much for all the help!